# Python list folders list by numeric order

Tags: python, list, directory

I'm getting list of all the folders in specific directory with this code:

```
TWITTER_FOLDER = os.path.join('TwitterPhotos')
dirs = [d for d in os.listdir(TWITTER_FOLDER) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(TWITTER_FOLDER, d))]
```

This is the array: `['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11']`.

And I want to get the array in this order:`['11','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1']`

So I use this code for that:

```
dirs.sort(key=lambda f: int(filter(str.isdigit, f)))
```

and when I use it I get this error:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'filter'
```

Any idea what is the problem? Or how I can sort it in another way?
It's important that the array will be sort by numeric order like:

```
12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

And not:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 12 11 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) returns an iterator, you need to join them back into a string before you can convert it to an integer

```
dirs.sort(key=lambda f: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, f))))
```

Comment: I didn't really understand where i need to insert it

Comment: @MTA - I've edited the code sample to be the full line as from your question

Answer (score 2):

Use `sorted` with key:

```
In [4]: sorted(f, key=lambda x: int(x), reverse=True)
Out[4]: ['11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

Or you can do `f.sort(key=lambda x:int(x), reverse=True)` for inplace sort.